# Disable parent link and only sub categories can click

Tags: magento-enterprise

How can I make the Parent link show but without anchor and can still hover so the sub categories will show and can click?

And is there a way for me to remove the "View all" link only under a specific parent link?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.' onclick="return false;">';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
} else {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
}
```

Hello,
To remove url, href functionality of the top menu categories, you can take the following steps:

1. Create some folder as this path: `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
2. Copy file Navigation.php from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block to add to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
3. Go to function `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`, `line 285` and put the above code:

you can find reference [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthr./viewthread/235462/)

Comment: Is there any other way through xml so I can add it over the admin? because I don't want to change the core codes

Comment: no not possible through admin section

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\topmenu\renderer.phtml
```

Search for word'View All' and comment that code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anisha Recommendation of removing the View All, to remove parent link option find the following code

```
$html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '.        $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';`
```

And Add `if` statement to check if its a parent link.

```
if($_hasChildren)
    { $html .= '<a href="#" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';   
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

        }
```